# How do I create a View Modifier that returns a view as well as an action?

Tags: ios, swiftui, popup, viewmodifier

I have created a View modifier alongside a sheet manager to deal with and create popup views throughout my project. It works perfectly with a simply popup and a close button to dismiss the view. Now what I am trying to is add more functionality to this sheet manager and modifier so that I can create/use heftier custom popups. By that I mean being able to use buttons and their actions on these popups.

view modifier code

```
    func popup(with sheetManager: SheetManager, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PopupViewModifier(sheetManager: sheetManager){ })
    }
```

function/view being called

```
struct PopupViewModifier: ViewModifier {
    @ObservedObject var sheetManager: SheetManager
    var popupAction: () -> (Void)
    
    
    func body(content: Content) -> some View {
        content
            .disabled(sheetManager.action.isPresented ? true : false )
            .blur(radius: sheetManager.action.isPresented ? 05 : 0)
            .overlay(alignment: .center) {
                if case let .present(config) = sheetManager.action {
                    switch config.type {
                    case .popupAlert:
                        PopupView(config: config) {
                            withAnimation {
                                sheetManager.dismiss()
                            }
                        }
                    case .soundProfileList:
                        SoundProfilePopupView(config: config) {
                            withAnimation {
                                sheetManager.dismiss()
                            }
                        } tappedProfile: {
                            popupAction()
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            .ignoresSafeArea()
    }
}
```

And how its called in the main view where I am trying to get the action callback

```
@EnvironmentObject var sheetManager: SheetManager

var body: some View {
    buttonToCallPopup( didPress: {
        sheetManager.present(with: Config.innit)
    }) {
        Text("Open up popup")
      }
    .popup(with: sheetManager) {
      print("button from popup has been pressed")
    }
}
```

SheetManager code

```
enum SheetType {
    case popupAlert
    case soundProfileList
}
final class SheetManager: ObservableObject {
    typealias Config = Action.Info
    @Published private(set) var action: Action = .na

    enum Action {
        struct Info {
            let systemName: String
            let title: String
            let content: String
            let type: SheetType
        }
        
        case na
        case present(info: Info)
        case dismiss
    }

    func present(with config: Config) {
        guard !action.isPresented else { return }
        self.action = .present(info: config)
    }
    
    func dismiss() {
        self.action = .dismiss
    }
}

extension SheetManager.Action {
    var isPresented: Bool {
        guard case .present(_) = self else {return false}
        return true
    }
}
```

I have tried creating a typealias of Void and View so that popup can return that, and I have also tried making popup return just a closure so that I could call

```
.popup(with: sheetManager) { // action I want taken on the button of the popup view
}
```

but I have met only build errors and no action. It took awhile to reduce the errors but there is still no action. the action I want to be done from the .popup is what I want propagated up from tappedProfile which is being called in the view modifier.

Comment: “I have met only build errors”—okay, so edit your question to include the code that produces build errors, and also include the errors. And please be sure to copy and paste accurately. I can see a couple of typos in the code you already posted that I do not think are the errors you need help with.

Answer (score 0):

```
 func popup(with sheetManager: SheetManager, action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        self.modifier(PopupViewModifier(sheetManager: sheetManager){  action() })
    }
```

action() was never being used, and just needed to be called in the function